# Double log when outputting to STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Context:

- Dockerized ruby application and started by following command

```
CMD ["rails", "server", "--no-log-to-stdout", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

- In my environments/*.rb i configured logger like below:

```
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
  message = msg
  message << " from #{progname}" if progname.present?
  content = JSON.dump(timestamp: datetime.to_s, severity: severity, message: message)
  content << "\n"
  content
end
```

When running the application, I have a weird issue of having two logs outputted.
Does anyone encountered the same problem?

Ruby on rails version: 7.1